# If $a\leq x_n \leq b$, then $a \leq \lim x_n \leq b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

Let {$x_n$} be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a \leq x_n \leq b$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $a \leq \lim x_n \leq b$.

How to prove this theorem? I started with the definition of a convergent sequence and I take $L$ as the limit of $x_n$. Further, I assumed that $a= L - \epsilon$ and $b = L + \epsilon $. Then,
$$\left| x_n - L \right| < \epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow L - \epsilon < x_n < L + \epsilon.$$
$$\Rightarrow a < x_n < b.$$

Is this logical?

Comment: Proving by contradiction is easy.

Comment: You have let $\varepsilon=L-a=b-L$ but these two might not be equal, let alone positive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\left\{x_n\right\}$ is a convergent sequence of points in $[a, b]$ and $\lim x_n = c$, then $c\in[a, b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248937/if-left-x-n-right-is-a-convergent-sequence-of-points-in-a-b-and-lim). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%20%5Cleq%20%5Clim%20x_n%20%5Cleq%20b%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n\geq a$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\{x_n\}$ is convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\geq a$.

Let's prove by contradiction. Suppose that $L:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n<a$, then by definition of limit for $\varepsilon:=\frac{a-L}{2}$ $\exists n_0=n_0(\varepsilon)$  such that $\forall n>n_0$ we have $|x_n-L|<\varepsilon=\frac{a-L}{2}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $$-\frac{a-L}{2}<x_n-L<\frac{a-L}{2} \Rightarrow$$ $$x_n<L+\frac{a-L}{2}=\frac{a+L}{2}<a.$$ So we derived contradiction and it proves that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\geq a$.

In the same way one can show that if $x_n\leq b$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n\leq b$.